# I need to remove duplicate products in an Array and sum their quantity in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, array-reduce

In the program, I fetch arrays of products from orders via API. The array contains a list with products that are duplicated.
I need to remove the duplicate products in the array and sum their quantities.

This is what the array I get looks like:

```
const productsAll = [
  {
    name: 'Product 1',
    ean: '1112223334445',
    sku: '4445',
    product_id: '70604566',
    quantity: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'Product 1',
    ean: '1112223334445',
    sku: '4445',
    product_id: '70604566',
    quantity: 3,
  },
  {
    name: 'Product 2',
    ean: '1112223334446',
    sku: '4446',
    product_id: '60404533',
    quantity: 2,
  },
  {
    name: 'Product 3',
    ean: '1112223334447',
    sku: '4447',
    product_id: '30504512',
    quantity: 8,
  },
];
```

I want to make it look like this after removing the duplicates and adding up the quantities:

Product 1 is reduced and the quantity is summed

```
[
  {
    name: 'Product 1',
    ean: '1112223334445',
    sku: '4445',
    product_id: '70604566',
    quantity: 4,
  },
  {
    name: 'Product 2',
    ean: '1112223334446',
    sku: '4446',
    product_id: '60404533',
    quantity: 2,
  },
  {
    name: 'Product 3',
    ean: '1112223334447',
    sku: '4447',
    product_id: '30504512',
    quantity: 8,
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below approach to achieve this. Create an object (`productsCheck` in my case) and loop through the `productsAll` array. If the name already exists in the object then add the quantity, else simple add the product to your object ( i.e `productsCheck`)

**Working code:**

```js
const productsAll = [{
    name: 'Product 1',
    ean: '1112223334445',
    sku: '4445',
    product_id: '70604566',
    quantity: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'Product 1',
    ean: '1112223334445',
    sku: '4445',
    product_id: '70604566',
    quantity: 3,
  },
  {
    name: 'Product 2',
    ean: '1112223334446',
    sku: '4446',
    product_id: '60404533',
    quantity: 2,
  },
  {
    name: 'Product 3',
    ean: '1112223334447',
    sku: '4447',
    product_id: '30504512',
    quantity: 8,
  },
];

const productsCheck = {}

productsAll.forEach(product => {
  if (product.name in productsCheck) {
    productsCheck[product.name].quantity += product.quantity
  } else {
    productsCheck[product.name] = product
  }
})

console.log(productsCheck)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create a map of quantities for each product, `productQuantities`, while removing duplicates.

I'm using `product_id` for the uniquifying key, one could use another if appropriate.

We'd also sum the totalQuantity in this loop.

```js
const productsAll = [ { name: 'Product 1', ean: '1112223334445', sku: '4445', product_id: '70604566', quantity: 1, }, { name: 'Product 1', ean: '1112223334445', sku: '4445', product_id: '70604566', quantity: 3, }, { name: 'Product 2', ean: '1112223334446', sku: '4446', product_id: '60404533', quantity: 2, }, { name: 'Product 3', ean: '1112223334447', sku: '4447', product_id: '30504512', quantity: 8, }, ];

const productQuantities = productsAll.reduce((acc, el) => {
    const uniqueKey = el.product_id;
    if (!acc[uniqueKey]) {
        acc[uniqueKey] = { name: el.name, quantity: el.quantity };
        acc.totalQuantity = (acc.totalQuantity || 0) + el.quantity;
    }
    return acc;
}, {})

console.log('Product quantities:', productQuantities);

console.log('Total quantity:', productQuantities.totalQuantity)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple logic

```js
const productsAll = [{
    name: 'Product 1',
    ean: '1112223334445',
    sku: '4445',
    product_id: '70604566',
    quantity: 1,},
    {
    name: 'Product 1',
    ean: '1112223334445',
    sku: '4445',
    product_id: '70604566',
    quantity: 3,
    },
    {
    name: 'Product 2',
    ean: '1112223334446',
    sku: '4446',
    product_id: '60404533',
    quantity: 2,
    },
    {
    name: 'Product 3',
    ean: '1112223334447',
    sku: '4447',
    product_id: '30504512',
    quantity: 8,
    },
    ];

    const products = {};
    const reducedProducts = [];
      productsAll.forEach((prd,idx) => {
      if (products[prd.product_id]) {
      prd.quantity += products[prd.product_id].quantity;
      products[prd.product_id].quantit =  prd.quantity;
      reducedProducts[products[prd.product_id].index] = prd; 
      }   
      else {
        products[prd.product_id] = {index:idx,quantity:prd.quantity};
        reducedProducts.push(prd)
      }
      })

     console.log(reducedProducts)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an improvement over Terry's answer, because it was not exactly what you ask.

Here you first construct a map using reduce, then convert that map to an array.

```js
const productsAll = [{ name: 'Product 1', ean: '1112223334445', sku: '4445', product_id: '70604566', quantity: 1, }, { name: 'Product 1', ean: '1112223334445', sku: '4445', product_id: '70604566', quantity: 3, }, { name: 'Product 2', ean: '1112223334446', sku: '4446', product_id: '60404533', quantity: 2, }, { name: 'Product 3', ean: '1112223334447', sku: '4447', product_id: '30504512', quantity: 8, },];

const productsMerged = Object.values(productsAll.reduce((acc, el) => {
    const uniqueKey = el.product_id;
    if (!acc[uniqueKey]) {
        acc[uniqueKey] = el;
    } else {
        acc[uniqueKey].quantity += el.quantity;
    }
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log('Product quantities:', productsMerged);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const productsAll = [
        { name: 'Product 1', ean: '1112223334445', sku: '4445', product_id: '70604566', quantity: 1, },
        { name: 'Product 1', ean: '1112223334445', sku: '4445', product_id: '70604566', quantity: 3, },
        { name: 'Product 2', ean: '1112223334446', sku: '4446', product_id: '60404533', quantity: 2, },
        { name: 'Product 3', ean: '1112223334447', sku: '4447', product_id: '30504512', quantity: 8, },
    ];
    
    const productQuantities = productsAll.reduce((acc, el) => {
        if (el.name in acc) {
            acc[el.name].quantity = el.quantity + acc[el.name].quantity
        } else {
            acc[el.name] = el;
        }
        
        return acc;
    }, {})
    
    console.log('Product quantities:', productQuantities);
```